# Jupyter kernel appears to have died error with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, kernel

I suddenly got this error message when trying to run a jupyter notebook.

This is the Jupyter lab server log:

[I 2023-08-18 10:29:58.239 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
[W 2023-08-18 10:29:58.239 ServerApp] kernel 3fc39549-66cd-4beb-95f2-2b6c8d489e7c restarted
[W 2023-08-18 10:29:58.240 ServerApp] kernel 3fc39549-66cd-4beb-95f2-2b6c8d489e7c restarted
[I 2023-08-18 10:29:58.248 ServerApp] Starting buffering for 3fc39549-66cd-4beb-95f2-2b6c8d489e7c:de56b2f3-a8f8-4177-99e1-b78d5b8d1d70
[I 2023-08-18 10:29:58.279 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 3fc39549-66cd-4beb-95f2-2b6c8d489e7c.
[I 2023-08-18 10:29:58.295 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 3fc39549-66cd-4beb-95f2-2b6c8d489e7c.

I isolated the different packages  that were being used and found out that the issue is most likely caused by tensorflow (a notebook with just 'import tensorflow' casues the same error). I tried reinstalling tensorflow on a new virtual environment with no other libraries, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It might be issue with the Tensorflow installation, make sure you need to install the latest version and also your Jupyter lab and Jupyter notebook are up to date . You can update by using this code `pip install --upgrade jupyterlab notebook`.Kindly try and let me know if issue is still persists.